# css messing up when dynamically appending to swiper js slide

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I have an array of elements and i'm trying to chunk the array and dynamically append every element to a swiper js slide. My chunk strategy is to chuck the array every 5 elements and I am looping on the chucked new arrays and appending every element of that array to the swiper slide. And whenever a new chuck array is found a new class called `.level3Items` will be created that will be housing the 5 `.swiper-slide` classes. Now my chuck strategy and adding every element to `.level3Items` works but my CSS messes up when the elements are dynamically added. For debugging I have 2 main divs below. The first one (`.level3`) is manually coded and it works right. On the second main div (`.level3_2`) I am adding the same code as the first main div but dynamically and as shows the CSS messes up. How can I fix this? How can I make  `.level3_2` look like `.level3`? Thanks in advance.

```js
const swiperRegular = new Swiper('#swiperRegular', {
  direction: 'horizontal',
  slidesPerView: 5,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  slidesPerGroup: 5,

  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    disabledClass: 'disabled_swiper_button'
  }
});

let myArray = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']
const result = Object.values(
  myArray.map((x, i) => ({
    grp: Math.floor(i / 5),
    val: x
  }))
  .reduce((acc, i) => {
    acc[i.grp] ||= [];
    acc[i.grp].push(i.val);
    return acc;
  }, {})
);
result.forEach((elm) => {
  const dataElem = $('<div class="level3Items"><div class="swiper" id="swiperRegular"><div class="swiper-button-prev"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i></div><div class="swiper-button-next"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i></div><div class="swiper-wrapper">');
  elm.forEach(item => {
    dataElem.find('.swiper-wrapper').append(`<div class="swiper-slide"><div class="topSwiperSlideItems"><div class="imgCon"><img src="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?q=60&c=sc&poi=%5B660%2C300%5D&w=1500&h=750&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F20%2F2021%2F07%2F23%2Fgrizzly-bear-1.jpg" /></div></div><div class="bottomSwiperSlideItems"><div class="textCon"><p>${item}</p></div></div></div>`)
  });
  $(".level3_2").append(dataElem);
  const swiperRegular = new Swiper('#swiperRegular', {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    slidesPerView: 5,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    slidesPerGroup: 5,

    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      disabledClass: 'disabled_swiper_button'
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.disabled_swiper_button {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.level3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-top: 1%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.level3_2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-top: 1%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.level3Items {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
}

.level3Items #swiperRegular {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 1.5%;
  padding-right: 1.5%;
}

.level3Items .swiper-button-prev {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 35%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.level3Items .swiper-button-prev::after {
  display: none;
}

.level3Items .swiper-button-prev i {
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.level3Items .swiper-button-next {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 35%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.level3Items .swiper-button-next::after {
  display: none;
}

.level3Items .swiper-button-next i {
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.level3Items .swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.level3Items .swiper-slide .topSwiperSlideItems {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: gold;
}

.level3Items .swiper-slide .topSwiperSlideItems .imgCon {
  display: grid;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}

.level3Items .swiper-slide .topSwiperSlideItems .imgCon img {
  width: 95.5%;
  height: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}

.level3Items .swiper-slide .bottomSwiperSlideItems {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: purple;
}

.level3Items .swiper-slide .bottomSwiperSlideItems .textCon {
  display: flex;
  width: 95%;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.level3Items .swiper-slide .bottomSwiperSlideItems .textCon p {
  font-size: 3vw;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3B6NwesSXE7YJlcLI9RpRqGf2p/EgVH8BgoKTaUrmKNDkHPStTQ3EyoYjCGXaOTS" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<!--working-->
<div class="level3">
  <div class="level3Items">
    <div class="swiper" id="swiperRegular">
      <div class="swiper-button-prev">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="topSwiperSlideItems">
            <div class="imgCon">
              <img src="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?q=60&c=sc&poi=%5B660%2C300%5D&w=1500&h=750&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F20%2F2021%2F07%2F23%2Fgrizzly-bear-1.jpg" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="bottomSwiperSlideItems">
            <div class="textCon">
              <p>test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="topSwiperSlideItems">
            <div class="imgCon">
              <img src="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?q=60&c=sc&poi=%5B660%2C300%5D&w=1500&h=750&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F20%2F2021%2F07%2F23%2Fgrizzly-bear-1.jpg" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="bottomSwiperSlideItems">
            <div class="textCon">
              <p>test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="topSwiperSlideItems">
            <div class="imgCon">
              <img src="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?q=60&c=sc&poi=%5B660%2C300%5D&w=1500&h=750&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F20%2F2021%2F07%2F23%2Fgrizzly-bear-1.jpg" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="bottomSwiperSlideItems">
            <div class="textCon">
              <p>test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--not working-->
<div class="level3_2">
</div>
```

Comment: The DOM structure of your working and non-working examples appears quite different, which I suspect is why your CSS isn't working as intended. In the working example, the `div.swiper-slide` elements are children of `div.swiper-wrapper`, while in your non-working example, they are children of `div.level3Items`.

Comment: @Josh yes you were right. I used ```.find('.swiper-wrapper').append(`...`)``` to target the ```swiper-wrapper``` when appending but now the swiper wrapper css is fixed but the swiper slide elements don't have the right css. I have updated the code above.

Comment: I tried initializing a new swiper in your example, and it worked for me. So, you should just need to initialize the library for the second object, like you did for the first using `new Swiper`. Currently, you're using classes for the selector, but they can't be the same. You can either change the class for the second instance, or better - use IDs.

Comment: @Josh I used IDs but nothing changed. Initializing a new swiper after appending worked though. I have updated the code above.

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it working! Cheers!